# BIRT 4.5 and Tomcat 8 compatibility issue

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, birt

My application is designed to generate reports using BIRT 4.5 reporting tool. This works fine with Tomcat 7 and Java 1.8. The same application when moved to Tomcat 8 gives exception. BIRT and JAVA versions remain the same only Tomcat is upgraded to version 8.

Is there any setting to be done in Eclipse for Tomcat 8 or any plugins or jar files to be installed?

Please find the stack trace below. Let me know what is the solution for

```
this.org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() 
for servlet [ViewerServlet] in context with path [/BIS] threw exception 
[Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 
[46] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\BIS\org\apache\jsp\webcontent\birt\pages\layout\Fram‌​esetFragment_jsp.java] 
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
```

Comment: It works for me. You should at least post the stacktrace of this exception

Comment: Please find the stack trace below. Let me know what is the solution for this.org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [ViewerServlet] in context with path [/BIS] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: [46] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\work\Catalina\localhost\BIS\org\apache\jsp\webcontent\birt\pages\layout\FramesetFragment_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory